# Spring servlet configuration file throws exception

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I get the following exception:

```
Build path is incomplete. Cannot find class file for com/hexgen/core/IHexGenDictionaryBased
```

This is the line where I get the above exception:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.hexgen.api.facade" />
```

This is the complete XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"
                                secured-annotations="enabled"
                                authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"
                                proxy-target-class="true">
        <sec:expression-handler ref="expressionHandler"/>
    </sec:global-method-security>

    <bean id="expressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
        <property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="hexgenPermissionEvaluator" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="hexgenPermissionEvaluator" class="com.hexgen.api.facade.security.HexGenPermissionEvaluator"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.hexgen.api.facade" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:annotation-config />
</beans>
```

Can anyone explain what I have to do to fix this?

Comment: Please consider an upvote if you found my answer pointing you in right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that wherever `com/hexgen/core/IHexGenDictionaryBased` class (or its .class file) is that location needs to be on your build path (or the classpath). If it's in some other hexgen-core.jar for example then make sure to add it to your build path (using Eclipse) or classpath (using the `-cp` parameter).

If the file in some other project directory then add its `/src` as a source directory for your Spring project and then all the `core` classes would automatically be on your classpath.

Answer (score 1):

I would think you need to have the component-scan look at a common package for both the api and the core.

Change `<context:component-scan base-package="com.hexgen.api.facade" />` to be `<context:component-scan base-package="com.hexgen" />` and it should pick up the core class it can't find.